# por que me dice error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'vendor\iluminate\database\Eloquent\Model' not found in

Tags: php, mysql, error404

He tratado por días de resolver este error, pero me dice que no encuentra la carpeta ya entre a vendor `\iluminate\database\Eloquent\Model; .php`

pero me sige apareciendo error:

> localhost Fatalerror:
>   UncaughtError:Class'vendor\iluminate\database\Eloquent\Model' not
>   found in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-database-crud-master\Task.php:4 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php-database-crud-master\index.php(9):
>   require_once()#1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php-database-crud-master\Task.php on line 4

**php**:

```
use iluminate\database\Eloquent\Model;
class Task extends vendor\iluminate\database\Eloquent\Model { protected $table ='tasks';
};
```

Comment: key sensitive `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`

Comment: Parece ser un *typo* es decir un error de escritura, dado lo cual tu pregunta terminará cerrada.

Comment: Para evitarte esto no hagas el archivo *desde cero*, en cambio en la consola ejecuta: `php artisan make:model ModelNombre` eso hará que el archivo de salida ya tenga la estructura de código mínima y correcta. PD: checa siempre la documentación.

Comment: por alguna razon no me ejecuta artisan

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando Laravel, debes usar el namespace correctamente para crear aplicaciones con mayor flexibilidad evitando problemas de conflictos entre clases y mejorando la legibilidad del código.

Iluminate no es correcto. Se escribe Illuminate con dos eles.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Task extends Model
{
   protected $table ='tasks';
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: ya pero ahora me dice lo siguiente Error fatal : Error no detectado: la clase

Comment: 'Illuminate \ Events \ Dispatcher' no se encuentra en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ php-database-crud-master \ index.php: 31 Seguimiento de pila: # 0 {main} arrojado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ php-database-crud-master \ index.php en la línea 31
// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

Comment: // Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();

Comment: El error que te lanza ahora es otro error distinto sin relación con el anterior. Puedes mostrarnos el código relacionado con el error?.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel estás utilizando?. ¿Has comprobado que exista en la estructura de directorios el archivo artisan.php?. Te recomendaría que te instalaras [laragon](https://laragon.org/download/index.html) para tus proyectos Laravel.